# Label shifted in groupplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, groupplots

I'm trying to plot 6 graphs using the `groupplot` environment.
From what I understood, the y label is placed on the left of the values of the axis, but as on different figures those values are different, it results in non aligned label, and it can also be placed on the figure of the left column.
Here is an example of what I get :
[image]
from this code :

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=2 by 3},
        width=6cm,
        height=4cm,
    ]
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N1},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 2.52402186393738
21 0.0392908006906509
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N2},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.00180898304097354
21 4.06462144851685
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N3},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.0086209699511528
21 0.431585133075714
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N4},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.034182284027338
21 2.88350582122803
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N5},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.0330703742802143
21 1.12964105606079
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N6},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.641332507133484
21 1.23090080350607e-08
};
\end{groupplot}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

How could I set those label to be aligned, and not superposed with the other figure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

To group style options I add `horizontal sep=4em` and define `yticklabel` width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[
        group style={group size=2 by 3,
                     horizontal sep=4em},     % <--- added
        width=6cm,  height=4cm,
    yticklabel style = {font=\small},  % <--- added
    yticklabel style = {text width=1.1em, align=right, font=\small},  % <--- added
                ]
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N1},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 2.52402186393738
21 0.0392908006906509
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N2},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.00180898304097354
21 4.06462144851685
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N3},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.0086209699511528
21 0.431585133075714
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N4},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.034182284027338
21 2.88350582122803
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N5},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.0330703742802143
21 1.12964105606079
};
\nextgroupplot[
xlabel={t},
ylabel={N6},
]
\addplot [thick, red, dashed]
table {%
4 0.641332507133484
21 1.23090080350607e-08
};
\end{groupplot}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: that works fine, thanks ! I missed the option when I looked at the documentation (https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-groupplots)